error when using align* environment, missing } inserted
I tried to use the align environment, to align multiple equations, but for some reason the compiler gives me dozens of error messages, saying either
Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.865 \end{align*}

or
Missing \right. inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \right .
l.865 \end{align*}

I checked my code for any extra \right)'s or }'s but I didn't find any. The relevant code is provided below. Any help is greatly appreciated!
\begin{align*}
&\forall x\forall y\forall z\left((z\in x\iff z\in y)\iff x=y\right),\\
&\forall x\forall y\exists z\forall v\left(v\in z\iff(v=x\vee v=y)\right),\\
&\forall x\exists y\forall z\left(z\in y\iff\forall\\
&\exists x\left(\forall y\left(\neg\exists z(z\in y)\implies y\in x\right)
\wedge\\
\text{  }&\wedge\forall w\left(w\in x\implies\forall u\left(\forall v
\left(v\in u\iff(v=w\vee v\in w)\right)\implies u\in x\right)\right)\right).
\end{align*}
Verify that
\begin{align*}
\forall z&\left(z\in f\implies\left(\exists x_1\exists y_1\left(x_1\in x
\wedge y_1\in y\wedge z=(x_1,y_1)\right)\right)\right)\wedge\\
&\wedge\forall x_1\left(x_1\in x\implies\exists y_1\exists z_1
\left(y_1\in y\wedge z=(x_1,y_1)\wedge z\in f\right)\right)\wedge\\
&\wedge\forall x_1\forall y_1\forall y_2\left(\exists z_1\exists z_2
\left(z_1\in f\wedge z_2\in f\wedge z_1=(x_1,y_1)\wedge z_2=(x_1,x_2)\right)
\implies\\
&\implies y_1=y_2\right)
\end{align*}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Culprit for your troubles is use of \left( and \right). Math expression between them had not to be broken int two or several lines. In This case you should use \bigl( and bigr) or \Bigl( and Bigr) etc. instead of them or simply omit all \left and right in your equation.

Incidentally, your equations feature 15 instances of \left( but only 14 instances of \right). That's not intentional, is it?

@Zarko, thank you, I was not aware of that issue. It is fixed now. :)
